# error with drawing rectangle in java swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, paint

The program compiles but I can't see the rectangle on the window, Can someone help me, I am new to this.
My goal is just to draw three rectangles on the window. for a traffic light program.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.lang.String;
import java.awt.Graphics;

class traffic extends Canvas implements ActionListener{
static JRadioButton b1,b2,b3;
  static JPanel jp = new JPanel();
static JFrame win= new JFrame("Traffic light");
traffic(){
  b1= new JRadioButton("red");
  b2= new JRadioButton("green");
  b3= new JRadioButton("yellow");
  jp.add(b1);
  jp.add(b2);
  jp.add(b3);

  win.add(jp);
    win.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
  win.setSize(500,500);
  win.setVisible(true);

  win.setDefaultCloseOperation(win.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
  b1.addActionListener(this);
  b2.addActionListener(this);
  b3.addActionListener(this);

}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) throws ArithmeticException
{ }
public void paint(Graphics g){

   g.setColor(Color.RED);
      g.fillRect(130, 30,100, 80);
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{    traffic tr= new traffic();
     tr.repaint();
}
}
```

Comment: 1) Be sure to set the window visible only *after* all component have been added and `pack()` is called. 2) After that is done you should see the buttons but no canvas. It is seemingly never added to anything. 3) Than, after the canvas is added (before the frame is packed) you should .. still not see it as the flow layout will respect the default size of 0 x 0. AFAIR, which with AWT, is not well.

Comment: .. 4) Wherever you got this code, put it back & start again. It'd be simpler to do it again, from the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), than fix what appears above.

Comment: I did as you advised, your right it's not painting at all only buttons are displayed when i call pack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Don't extend `Canvas` (or even use it), but do extend `JPanel`.
- add the `JPanel` to the `JFrame` - (`win.add(this)`)
- Your button's are filling the panel, hiding the background.  Give them a size
- Add them to the `JPanel` just using `add(b1)` etc
- Don't override `paint`, but do override `paintComponent`.  And do it as follows:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
   super.paintComponent(g);
   // your stuff here
```

- Don't set the size of the `JFrame`. Set the size of the `JPanel`.  Otherwise your `JFrame` border absorbs some of the size, making your panel smaller than you may want. Do it as follows.

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
   return new Dimension(500,500);
}
```

You still have other logic to work out but this should get you started.

**Style corrections**

These are not critical to the execution of your code but important to learn.

- By convention, classes begin with an upper case character.
- Use the class name, not an instance when referring to static values.

```
win.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked :)  and I will keep the tips in mind.

Comment: You're welcome. One more suggestion you may want to try.  Add your buttons to a separate JPanel.  And then add that panel to your other panel.  It helps to control the buttons as a group when placing them in a main panel.  In fact, using JPanel's with different layout managers is a common practice to build GUI's, as panels may contain other panels, etc.

Comment: Sure, I solved it, will post the code. I have to submit it by tomorrow so I will keep it in mind next time :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.lang.String;
import java.awt.Graphics;

  class traffic extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
static JRadioButton b1,b2,b3;
static JLabel l1;
traffic(){

JFrame win= new JFrame("Traffic light");
  l1= new JLabel("my name");
  b1= new JRadioButton("red");
  b2= new JRadioButton("green");
  b3= new JRadioButton("yellow");
  this.getPreferredSize();
  l1.setBounds(40,100,60,50);
  win.setSize(500,500);
  b1.setBounds(70,100,60,50);
  b2.setBounds(150,100,60,50);
  b3.setBounds(140,150,60,50);
  this.add(b1);
  this.add(b2);
  this.add(b3);
  this.add(l1);
  win.add(this);

  win.setVisible(true);
  win.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
  b1.addActionListener(this);
  b2.addActionListener(this);
  b3.addActionListener(this);

}
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
   return new Dimension(500,500);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{     if(e.getSource()==b1)
  {     b2.setSelected(false);
        b3.setSelected(false);
        this.repaint();
  }
     else if(e.getSource()==b2)
     { this.repaint();
       b1.setSelected(false);
       b3.setSelected(false);
     }

     else if(e.getSource()==b3)
     {  this.repaint();
       b1.setSelected(false);
       b2.setSelected(false);
     }

}
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
   super.paintComponent(g);
 if(b1.isSelected())
 {
   g.setColor(Color.RED);
   g.fillRect(150, 60,100, 100);
 }
 else if(b2.isSelected())
 { g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
  g.fillRect(150, 60,100, 100);
}
else if(b3.isSelected())
{
  g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
  g.fillRect(150, 60,100, 100);

}
else{
  g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
  g.fillRect(150, 60,100, 100);
}
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
      traffic tr= new traffic();



}





}
```